# i've accidentally edited my wp-config.php now i can't remember my infos

Tags: wordpress, localhost, webmatrix

when i trying to upload my files to server i've accidentally changed my wp-config.php details according to my server. Now i think i have to export my settings from localhost for import to server. But since i've changed my wp-config.php, i can't access my local database.

So is there any way to recover my details? Or can i create new user for webmatrix to access database. I'm not familiar with these things so i'm stuck.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you mean you've changed your database credentials in wp-config then you should be able to log into your hosting provider panel and access database information from there, and assign a new password to the database etc and update your config file.

Comment: no, i mean i've changed my wp-config.php file while uploading my website to server. Server side is fine because i've changed my config file according to server database. But now i can not acces my local database for export my settings and apply to server. Because i've changed it before the actual upload, now i'm stuck. cant access my local database.

Comment: i'm asking is there any way to recover my local database config to access local wordpress website. sorry for my english if you misunderstood.

Comment: what's your local server? they usually have defaults?

Comment: @user2572155 Do you use Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL?